# how can I get enum value by name string

Tags: java, enums

I want to get the enum value by name string,

this the enum code:
package practice;

```
enum Mobile {
  Samsung(400),
  Nokia(250),
  Motorola(325);

  int price;
  Mobile(int p) {
    price = p;
  }
  int showPrice() {
    return price;
  }
}
```

I can get the class name and the name string

```
Class enumClass = Class.forName("practice.Mobile");
String name = "Samsung";
```

how can I get the Samsung value 400 only use enumClass and name?
thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean like `Enum.valueOf(String)`? e.g `Mobile.valueOf("Nokia")`

Comment: *Unrelated:* Standard naming convention is for that method to be named `getPrice()`, not `showPrice()`, especially since the method doesn't actually *show* anything.

Comment: @Edwin yes, Enum,valueOf(enumClass, name), can we get name corresponding value 400 by this type method?

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like:

```
final Mobile mobile = Mobile.valueOf("Samsung");
final int price = mobile.showPrice();
```

(you do have to change the scope of the method `showPrice()` to `public`).

Comment: Why the final keywords? Not required and does add zero value to the example.

Comment: @Gabe  how about use variable enumClass? not mobile.

Answer (score 2):

as you may know, there is a valueOf method in every enum, which returns the constant just by resolving the name(read about exceptions when the string is invalid.)

now, since your enum has another fields associated to the constants you need to search its value by matching those fields too...

this is a possible solution using

## java 8

```
public enum ProgramOfStudy {
    ComputerScience("CS"), 
    AutomotiveComputerScience("ACS"), 
    BusinessInformatics("BI");

    public final String shortCut;

    ProgramOfStudy(String shortCut) {
        this.shortCut = shortCut;
    }

    public static ProgramOfStudy getByShortCut(String shortCut) {

        return Arrays.stream(ProgramOfStudy.values()).filter(v -> v.shortCut.equals(shortCut)).findAny().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

so you can "resolve" the enum by searching its "shortcut"

like

```
System.out.println(ProgramOfStudy.getByShortCut("CS"));
```